# Put 2 Shaders Script into 1 Shader Script (Bend World + Cartoon Shader)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I have 2 shaders that work individually. a curved world and a cartoon that I picked up here https://github.com/unity3d-jp/UnityChanToonShaderVer2_Project.

here are the 2 scripts that are concerned.

Curved

```
Shader "Custom/Curved"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
 
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 200
 
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert addshadow
 
        // Global Shader values
        uniform float2 _BendAmount;
        uniform float3 _BendOrigin;
        uniform float _BendFalloff;
 
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
 
        struct Input
        {
              float2 uv_MainTex;
        };
 
        float4 Curve(float4 v)
        {
              //HACK: Considerably reduce amount of Bend
              _BendAmount *= .0001;
 
              float4 world = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v);
 
              float dist = length(world.xz-_BendOrigin.xz);
 
              dist = max(0, dist-_BendFalloff);
 
              // Distance squared
              dist = dist*dist;
 
              world.xy += dist*_BendAmount;
              return mul(unity_WorldToObject, world);
        }
 
        void vert(inout appdata_full v)
        {
              v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex);
        }
 
        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
              fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
              o.Albedo = c.rgb;
              o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
 
        ENDCG
    }
 
      Fallback "Mobile/Diffuse"
}
```

Cartoon

```
Shader "UnityChanToonShader/Toon_DoubleShadeWithFeather" {
    Properties {
        [HideInInspector] _simpleUI ("SimpleUI", Int ) = 0
        [HideInInspector] _utsVersion ("Version", Float ) = 2.07
        [HideInInspector] _utsTechnique ("Technique", int ) = 0 //DWF
        [Enum(OFF,0,FRONT,1,BACK,2)] _CullMode("Cull Mode", int) = 2  //OFF/FRONT/BACK
        _MainTex ("BaseMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HideInInspector] _BaseMap ("BaseMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BaseColor ("BaseColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        //v.2.0.5 : Clipping/TransClipping for SSAO Problems in PostProcessing Stack.
        //If you want to go back the former SSAO results, comment out the below line.
        [HideInInspector] _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        //
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_Base ("Is_LightColor_Base", Float ) = 1
        _1st_ShadeMap ("1st_ShadeMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        //v.2.0.5
        [Toggle(_)] _Use_BaseAs1st ("Use BaseMap as 1st_ShadeMap", Float ) = 0
        _1st_ShadeColor ("1st_ShadeColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_1st_Shade ("Is_LightColor_1st_Shade", Float ) = 1
        _2nd_ShadeMap ("2nd_ShadeMap", 2D) = "white" {}
        //v.2.0.5
        [Toggle(_)] _Use_1stAs2nd ("Use 1st_ShadeMap as 2nd_ShadeMap", Float ) = 0
        _2nd_ShadeColor ("2nd_ShadeColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_2nd_Shade ("Is_LightColor_2nd_Shade", Float ) = 1
        _NormalMap ("NormalMap", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _BumpScale ("Normal Scale", Range(0, 1)) = 1
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_NormalMapToBase ("Is_NormalMapToBase", Float ) = 0
        //v.2.0.4.4
        [Toggle(_)] _Set_SystemShadowsToBase ("Set_SystemShadowsToBase", Float ) = 1
        _Tweak_SystemShadowsLevel ("Tweak_SystemShadowsLevel", Range(-0.5, 0.5)) = 0
        //v.2.0.6
        _BaseColor_Step ("BaseColor_Step", Range(0, 1)) = 0.5
        _BaseShade_Feather ("Base/Shade_Feather", Range(0.0001, 1)) = 0.0001
        _ShadeColor_Step ("ShadeColor_Step", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        _1st2nd_Shades_Feather ("1st/2nd_Shades_Feather", Range(0.0001, 1)) = 0.0001
        [HideInInspector] _1st_ShadeColor_Step ("1st_ShadeColor_Step", Range(0, 1)) = 0.5
        [HideInInspector] _1st_ShadeColor_Feather ("1st_ShadeColor_Feather", Range(0.0001, 1)) = 0.0001
        [HideInInspector] _2nd_ShadeColor_Step ("2nd_ShadeColor_Step", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        [HideInInspector] _2nd_ShadeColor_Feather ("2nd_ShadeColor_Feather", Range(0.0001, 1)) = 0.0001
        //v.2.0.5
        _StepOffset ("Step_Offset (ForwardAdd Only)", Range(-0.5, 0.5)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_Filter_HiCutPointLightColor ("PointLights HiCut_Filter (ForwardAdd Only)", Float ) = 1
        //
        _Set_1st_ShadePosition ("Set_1st_ShadePosition", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Set_2nd_ShadePosition ("Set_2nd_ShadePosition", 2D) = "white" {}
        //
        _HighColor ("HighColor", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
//v.2.0.4 HighColor_Tex
        _HighColor_Tex ("HighColor_Tex", 2D) = "white" {}
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_HighColor ("Is_LightColor_HighColor", Float ) = 1
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_NormalMapToHighColor ("Is_NormalMapToHighColor", Float ) = 0
        _HighColor_Power ("HighColor_Power", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_SpecularToHighColor ("Is_SpecularToHighColor", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_BlendAddToHiColor ("Is_BlendAddToHiColor", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_UseTweakHighColorOnShadow ("Is_UseTweakHighColorOnShadow", Float ) = 0
        _TweakHighColorOnShadow ("TweakHighColorOnShadow", Range(0, 1)) = 0
//ハイカラーマスク.
        _Set_HighColorMask ("Set_HighColorMask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Tweak_HighColorMaskLevel ("Tweak_HighColorMaskLevel", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _RimLight ("RimLight", Float ) = 0
        _RimLightColor ("RimLightColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_RimLight ("Is_LightColor_RimLight", Float ) = 1
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_NormalMapToRimLight ("Is_NormalMapToRimLight", Float ) = 0
        _RimLight_Power ("RimLight_Power", Range(0, 1)) = 0.1
        _RimLight_InsideMask ("RimLight_InsideMask", Range(0.0001, 1)) = 0.0001
        [Toggle(_)] _RimLight_FeatherOff ("RimLight_FeatherOff", Float ) = 0
//リムライト追加プロパティ.
        [Toggle(_)] _LightDirection_MaskOn ("LightDirection_MaskOn", Float ) = 0
        _Tweak_LightDirection_MaskLevel ("Tweak_LightDirection_MaskLevel", Range(0, 0.5)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Add_Antipodean_RimLight ("Add_Antipodean_RimLight", Float ) = 0
        _Ap_RimLightColor ("Ap_RimLightColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_Ap_RimLight ("Is_LightColor_Ap_RimLight", Float ) = 1
        _Ap_RimLight_Power ("Ap_RimLight_Power", Range(0, 1)) = 0.1
        [Toggle(_)] _Ap_RimLight_FeatherOff ("Ap_RimLight_FeatherOff", Float ) = 0
//リムライトマスク.
        _Set_RimLightMask ("Set_RimLightMask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Tweak_RimLightMaskLevel ("Tweak_RimLightMaskLevel", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
//ここまで.
        [Toggle(_)] _MatCap ("MatCap", Float ) = 0
        _MatCap_Sampler ("MatCap_Sampler", 2D) = "black" {}
        //v.2.0.6
        _BlurLevelMatcap ("Blur Level of MatCap_Sampler", Range(0, 10)) = 0
        _MatCapColor ("MatCapColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_MatCap ("Is_LightColor_MatCap", Float ) = 1
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_BlendAddToMatCap ("Is_BlendAddToMatCap", Float ) = 1
        _Tweak_MatCapUV ("Tweak_MatCapUV", Range(-0.5, 0.5)) = 0
        _Rotate_MatCapUV ("Rotate_MatCapUV", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        //v.2.0.6
        [Toggle(_)] _CameraRolling_Stabilizer ("Activate CameraRolling_Stabilizer", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_NormalMapForMatCap ("Is_NormalMapForMatCap", Float ) = 0
        _NormalMapForMatCap ("NormalMapForMatCap", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _BumpScaleMatcap ("Scale for NormalMapforMatCap", Range(0, 1)) = 1
        _Rotate_NormalMapForMatCapUV ("Rotate_NormalMapForMatCapUV", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_UseTweakMatCapOnShadow ("Is_UseTweakMatCapOnShadow", Float ) = 0
        _TweakMatCapOnShadow ("TweakMatCapOnShadow", Range(0, 1)) = 0
//MatcapMask
        _Set_MatcapMask ("Set_MatcapMask", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Tweak_MatcapMaskLevel ("Tweak_MatcapMaskLevel", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Inverse_MatcapMask ("Inverse_MatcapMask", Float ) = 0
        //v.2.0.5
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_Ortho ("Orthographic Projection for MatCap", Float ) = 0
        //v.2.0.7 Emissive
        [KeywordEnum(SIMPLE,ANIMATION)] _EMISSIVE("EMISSIVE MODE", Float) = 0
        _Emissive_Tex ("Emissive_Tex", 2D) = "white" {}
        [HDR]_Emissive_Color ("Emissive_Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _Base_Speed ("Base_Speed", Float ) = 0
        _Scroll_EmissiveU ("Scroll_EmissiveU", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        _Scroll_EmissiveV ("Scroll_EmissiveV", Range(-1, 1)) = 0
        _Rotate_EmissiveUV ("Rotate_EmissiveUV", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_PingPong_Base ("Is_PingPong_Base", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_ColorShift ("Activate ColorShift", Float ) = 0
        [HDR]_ColorShift ("ColorSift", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _ColorShift_Speed ("ColorShift_Speed", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_ViewShift ("Activate ViewShift", Float ) = 0
        [HDR]_ViewShift ("ViewSift", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_ViewCoord_Scroll ("Is_ViewCoord_Scroll", Float ) = 0
        //
//Outline
        [KeywordEnum(NML,POS)] _OUTLINE("OUTLINE MODE", Float) = 0
        _Outline_Width ("Outline_Width", Float ) = 0
        _Farthest_Distance ("Farthest_Distance", Float ) = 100
        _Nearest_Distance ("Nearest_Distance", Float ) = 0.5
        _Outline_Sampler ("Outline_Sampler", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Outline_Color ("Outline_Color", Color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_BlendBaseColor ("Is_BlendBaseColor", Float ) = 0
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_LightColor_Outline ("Is_LightColor_Outline", Float ) = 1
        //v.2.0.4
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_OutlineTex ("Is_OutlineTex", Float ) = 0
        _OutlineTex ("OutlineTex", 2D) = "white" {}
        //Offset parameter
        _Offset_Z ("Offset_Camera_Z", Float) = 0
        //v.2.0.4.3 Baked Nrmal Texture for Outline
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_BakedNormal ("Is_BakedNormal", Float ) = 0
        _BakedNormal ("Baked Normal for Outline", 2D) = "white" {}
        //GI Intensity
        _GI_Intensity ("GI_Intensity", Range(0, 1)) = 0
        //For VR Chat under No effective light objects
        _Unlit_Intensity ("Unlit_Intensity", Range(0.001, 4)) = 1
        //v.2.0.5 
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_Filter_LightColor ("VRChat : SceneLights HiCut_Filter", Float ) = 0
        //Built-in Light Direction
        [Toggle(_)] _Is_BLD ("Advanced : Activate Built-in Light Direction", Float ) = 0
        _Offset_X_Axis_BLD (" Offset X-Axis (Built-in Light Direction)", Range(-1, 1)) = -0.05
        _Offset_Y_Axis_BLD (" Offset Y-Axis (Built-in Light Direction)", Range(-1, 1)) = 0.09
        [Toggle(_)] _Inverse_Z_Axis_BLD (" Inverse Z-Axis (Built-in Light Direction)", Float ) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {
            "RenderType"="Opaque"
        }
        Pass {
            Name "Outline"
            Tags {
            }
            Cull Front

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            //#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            //#pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
            //#pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles gles3 metal vulkan xboxone ps4 switch
            #pragma target 3.0
            //V.2.0.4
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_OUTLINE_CLIPPING_NO 
            #pragma multi_compile _OUTLINE_NML _OUTLINE_POS
            //アウトライン処理はUTS_Outline.cgincへ.
            #include "UCTS_Outline.cginc"
            ENDCG
        }
//ToonCoreStart
        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardBase"
            }

            Cull[_CullMode]
            
            
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            //#define UNITY_PASS_FORWARDBASE
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "AutoLight.cginc"
            #include "Lighting.cginc"
            #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase_fullshadows
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles gles3 metal vulkan xboxone ps4 switch
            #pragma target 3.0

            //v.2.0.4
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_CLIPPING_OFF
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_PASS_FWDBASE
            //v.2.0.7
            #pragma multi_compile _EMISSIVE_SIMPLE _EMISSIVE_ANIMATION
            //
            #include "UCTS_DoubleShadeWithFeather.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }
        Pass {
            Name "FORWARD_DELTA"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ForwardAdd"
            }

            Blend One One
            Cull[_CullMode]
            
            
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            //#define UNITY_PASS_FORWARDADD
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "AutoLight.cginc"
            #include "Lighting.cginc"
            //for Unity2018.x
            #pragma multi_compile_fwdadd_fullshadows
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles gles3 metal vulkan xboxone ps4 switch
            #pragma target 3.0

            //v.2.0.4
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_CLIPPING_OFF
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_PASS_FWDDELTA
            #include "UCTS_DoubleShadeWithFeather.cginc"

            ENDCG
        }
        Pass {
            Name "ShadowCaster"
            Tags {
                "LightMode"="ShadowCaster"
            }
            Offset 1, 1
            Cull Off
            
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            //#define UNITY_PASS_SHADOWCASTER
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "Lighting.cginc"
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles gles3 metal vulkan xboxone ps4 switch
            #pragma target 3.0
            //v.2.0.4
            #pragma multi_compile _IS_CLIPPING_OFF
            #include "UCTS_ShadowCaster.cginc"
            ENDCG
        }
//ToonCoreEnd
    }
    FallBack "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit"
    CustomEditor "UnityChan.UTS2GUI"
}
```

Sorry it's a bit messy but i don't really know how to do it i've copy/paste one into the other and it doesn't work... i don't really understand how shader work.

Comment: Toon shader is including other `cginc` files which define `vert`. `UCTS_Outline.cginc`, `UCTS_DoubleShadeWithFeather.cginc`, etc. A good start would be to  define the  `Curve` function from the **Curved** code and call it at the start of the `vert` functions in these `.cginc` files and overwrite the v.vertex value they work with like `VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) { v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex); /* rest of vert function */}`

Comment: And where do I find the VertexOutput vert on the toon shader ?

Comment: Toon shader is including other cginc files which define vert. `UCTS_Outline.cginc`, `UCTS_DoubleShadeWithFeather.cginc`, etc.

Comment: ok so i put the curved function in all the other cginc file and ovewrite the output with `VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) { v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex); /* rest of vert function */}`? is that so ?

sorry I am bit new to shaders

Comment: Now that `Curve` is defined, it should only require inserting one line, `v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex);` at the start of the `vert` functions. That is what does the overwrite of the `v.vertex` value.

Comment: Oh! and one more thing. Add 
        `uniform float2 _BendAmount;
        uniform float3 _BendOrigin;
        uniform float _BendFalloff;` in each of those `UCTS_*.cginc` files .

Comment: ok but there no vert function in the "Toon" script I put above Am I wrong ? 

and to define the function i just need to put  `float4 Curve(float4 v) {...}` in the toon script between `CGPROGRAM` and `ENDCG` and above the `vert` function where I call it by writing `v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex)` ?

Comment: yes the global variables uniform !

Comment: For the third time, Toon shader is including other `cginc` files which define `vert`. `UCTS_Outline.cginc`, `UCTS_DoubleShadeWithFeather.cginc`, etc. Line 58 of [UCTS_Outline.cginc](https://github.com/unity3d-jp/UnityChanToonShaderVer2_Project/blob/release/legacy/2.0/Assets/Toon/Shader/UCTS_Outline.cginc#L58) literally has `VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {` so I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: ok so now i have a stupid question i define the curve function in UCTS_outline.cginc juste before before vert where i call it ?

Comment: Good question. Yes that should work. So `UCTS_Outline.cginc` should look something like `/* ... */ struct VertexOutput { /* ... */ };  float4 Curve(float4 v) { /* ... */ } VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) { v.vertex = Curve(v.vertex); VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0; /* ... */`

Comment: I did this https://github.com/TheMrTBO/Shader-Toon---Curved but i can't load the UCTS i have this type of error Shader error in `'UnityChanToonShader/Toon_DoubleShadeWithFeather': failed to open source file: 'UCTS_Outline.cginc'`

Comment: Done It works ! 
I've finally understood, I've put the global variable, declared the function curve and put the new v.vertex in the VertexOutput vert on every UCTS.

Thank you for your help and for taking the time  @Ruzihm

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help! Consider writing a [self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/1092820) below, then you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359). That will help future visitors coming here with similar questions find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Done It works ! I've finally understood, I've put the global variable, declared the function curve and put the new v.vertex in the VertexOutput vert on every UCTS file.